# Scheduled timer gets stuck in angular after switching to another window on browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-idle, stay-logged-in

I am trying to implement Auto Logout feature after 20minutes of inactivity of user. Therefore, I used **@ng-idle/core** npm package inside my project to set user idle after 20minutes of inactivity and to display popup which asks either **logout** or **stay logged in** for 60seconds which will get decremented after every second. In the start I had a problem with seconds mismatched issue while using multiple tabs in same browser window. To get rid of this issue I have implemented startInterval() and stored seconds into localStorage.
Now, if I am using multiple window of same browser seconds in popup gets stuck after 2 times pressing **stay logged in**. Angular project window gets freeze after inactivity of the window of same browser. It would be helpful if anyone comes with a solution of my problem.
Thanks

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, HostListener, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MenuItem } from "primeng/api";
import { LoginService } from "./components/login/login.service";
import { Idle, DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES } from "@ng-idle/core";
import { DialogService } from "primeng/dynamicdialog";
import { Keepalive } from "@ng-idle/keepalive";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  providers: [DialogService],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  items: MenuItem[];
  title = "maincontainer";

  idleState = "NOT_STARTED";
  countdown?: number = null;
  lastPing?: Date = null;
  showAutoLogout: Boolean = false;
  showSpinner: Boolean = false;
  setInterval: any;

  // On tab close event reset idle event
  // @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  // beforeunloadHandler(event) {
  //   this.reset();
  // }

  constructor(
    public loginService: LoginService,
    private idle: Idle,
    private keepalive: Keepalive,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    // Default timer started set to false in local storage
    localStorage.setItem('timerStarted', 'false');

    // set idle parameters
    idle.setIdle(60); // how long can they be inactive before considered idle, in seconds
    idle.setTimeout(60); // how long can they be idle before considered timed out, in seconds
    idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES); // provide sources that will "interrupt" aka provide events indicating the user is active

    // do something when the user becomes idle
    idle.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => {
      this.idleState = "IDLE";
      idle.clearInterrupts();
      this.checkLogin();
    });

    // do something when the user is no longer idle
    idle.onIdleEnd.subscribe(() => {
      if (localStorage.getItem("bearerToken")) {
        this.idleState = "NOT_IDLE";
        this.reset();
      } else {
        this.logout();
      }
    });
    // do something when the user has timed out
    idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
      this.idleState = "TIMED_OUT";
      this.countdown = null;
      // Removed event logout from idle timeout which we have manually handled in custom interval timeout
      // this.showAutoLogout = false;
      // this.logout();
    });
    // do something as the timeout countdown does its thing
    idle.onTimeoutWarning.subscribe((seconds) => {
      this.checkLogin();
      this.showAutoLogout = true;
      // Checked condition if interval is already not started trigger interval
      if (localStorage.getItem('timerStarted') == "false") {
        this.startInterval();
      }
      // this.countdown = seconds;
    });

    // set keepalive parameters, omit if not using keepalive
    //  keepalive.interval(15); // will ping at this interval while not idle, in seconds
    keepalive.onPing.subscribe(() => {
      this.lastPing = new Date();
      // this.reset();
    }); // do something when it pings
  }

  startInterval() {
    // If interval is triggered timer started set to true and countdows set to 60 in local storage
    localStorage.setItem('timerStarted', 'true');
    localStorage.setItem('timerCountdown', JSON.stringify(60));
    this.setInterval = setInterval(() => {
      // Dedcuted timer countdown with 1 every second and set again in local storage to display in popup
      let timerCountdown = +localStorage.getItem('timerCountdown') - 1;
      localStorage.setItem('timerCountdown', JSON.stringify(timerCountdown));
      // If timer countdown reach to 0 then action event logout and hide logout popup
      if (localStorage.getItem('timerCountdown') == "0") {
        this.showAutoLogout = false;
        this.logout();
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

  // Made method to return timer countdown
  get getCountdown() {
    return localStorage.getItem('timerCountdown');
  }

  checkLogin() {
    if (!this.loginService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.idle.stop();
      window.location.href = "/login";
    }
  }

  reset() {
    // Cleared timer started, countdown from local storage and the interval
    localStorage.setItem('timerStarted', 'false');
    localStorage.setItem('timerCountdown', JSON.stringify(60));
    clearInterval(this.setInterval);
    // we'll call this method when we want to start/reset the idle process
    // reset any component state and be sure to call idle.watch()
    this.idle.stop();
    this.idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);
    this.idleState = "NOT_IDLE.";
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    this.idle.watch();
    this.countdown = null;
    this.lastPing = null;
    this.showAutoLogout = false;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    window.addEventListener('storage', function (event) {
      if (event.key == "loggedIn") {
        if (localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") == 'true') {
          window.location.reload();
        }
        else {
          window.location.href = '/login';
        }
      }
    }, false);

    // right when the component initializes, start reset state and start watching
    if (this.loginService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.reset();
    }

    this.loginService.userLoggedIn.subscribe(() => {
      this.reset();
    });

    this.loginService.userLoggedOut.subscribe(() => {
      localStorage.clear();
      window.localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', 'false');
      window.location.reload();
    });
  }

  logout() {
    // this.loginService.userLoggedOut.emit();
    this.showSpinner = true;
    let token = localStorage.getItem("bearerToken");
    let logoutData = {
      loginId: localStorage.getItem("loginId"),
      loginReportId: localStorage.getItem("loginReportId"),
    };
    if (!this.loginService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.loginService.userLoggedOut.emit();
      return;
    }
    this.loginService.logout(logoutData, token).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.showSpinner = false;
        this.loginService.userLoggedOut.emit();
        this.idle.stop();
      },
      (error) => {
        this.showSpinner = false;
        this.loginService.userLoggedOut.emit();
        this.idle.stop();
      }
    );
  }
}
```